Is it possible to play RAW video encapsulated in YUYV 4:2:2 format using gstreamer?
I have custom USB UVC camera based on Infineon CX3 controller.
I send RAW10 (1 pixel in two bytes, LSB first, RGGB Bayer pattern) data frames incapsulated in YUYV 4:2:2 format.
Is it possible to play with format using gst-launch-1.0 app?
Now, I can play camera stream using next pipline:
gst-launch-1.0.exe -v autovideosrc ! video/x-raw,width=1280,height=720,format=YUY2 ! videoconvert ! fpsdisplaysink
capture
But if I try to add debyer:
gst-launch-1.0.exe -v autovideosrc ! video/x-raw,width=1280,height=720,format=YUY2 ! videoconvert ! video/x-bayer,format=rggb,width=1280,height=720 ! bayer2rgb ! videoconvert ! fpsdisplaysink
I see:
WARNING: erroneous pipeline: could not link videoconvert0 to videoconvert1, neither element can handle caps video/x-bayer, width=(int)1280, height=(int)720, format=(string)rggb
I can do color demosaic using v4l2 and opencv, but I would like to know if this can be done using gstreamer?

You probably dont need the second videoconvert element?

You can check the compatibilities of your elements by inspecting their capabilities:
gst-inspect-1.0 bayer2rgb
gst-inspect-1.0 videoconvert

While I didn't find any gstreamer element that directly converts YUV to Bayer, you can add one more step:
YUV->RGB using videoconvert
RGB->Bayer using rgb2bayer
I tested in on a sample pipeline, simulating your input using videotestsrc:
gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc ! video/x-raw, width=1280, height=720, format=YUY2 ! videoconvert ! rgb2bayer ! video/x-bayer,format=rggb, width=1280, height=720 ! bayer2rgb ! videoconvert ! fpsdisplaysink

